# Array to string conversion - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to store the id of the selected item in my drop down but I get an error `array to string conversion`.

**HTML**

```php
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Age</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="age" name="age[]" mulitple>
            @foreach($ages as $age)
                <option value="{!! $age->id !!}" @if(in_array($age->id, $selectedAges)) selected="selected" @endif >
                    {!! $age->id !!}
                </option>
            @endforeach
        </select> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```php
$user = new User(array(
    'name' => $request->get('name'),                     
    'age' => $request->get('age'),
));

$user->save();
```

Comment: How you want to store like `[10,20,30]` inside age column, like this ? `10,20,30` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `name="age[]"` sends an array. change it to `name="age"`

Comment: Yeah, and while you are fixing that, also fix the "mulitple" typo.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `mulitple` and if you want to store in single column for `[10,20,30]` as `10,20,30` which is varchar not integer try like this

First change name in html from `name="age[]"` to `name="age"` and then get value in controller

```
'age' => implode(",",$request->age),
```